# Getting HTTP Status Code from multiple URLs using curl_multi?

Tags: php, curl

Alright, so I'm using curl_multi_* to connect to various sites simultaneously. How would I return the HTTP Status Code to a variable for comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the request id through [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) and you'll get back an array containing a key of http_code.